Journey builder update contact activity to sync on SF CRM
I have an email campaign with a confirmation button. I am planning to use the journey builder  to send this out to users who selected a particular date for an upcoming event and confirm their attendance. I am planning to use the engagement split and update contact activity to be able to capture this response. If the user clicks on the button, update the attribute value to True. I want to be able to see the updated values on my salesforce CRM as well. I am not sure how to go about this sync? Is there an easy way to do this for a beginner? Please help

You CAN do this using engagement split and object activity (not Update Contact - this isn't a cross cloud function), but you will also need to use a wait step to ensure clicks are registered between the email is sent out and the click is registered.
I will although recommend doing the logic in a landing page, using UpdateSingleSalesforceObject function to set the field immediately after the click. This will of course require some coding, but this is for sure on the "easy" side. You will need to build a landing page regardless, to confirm the click.
Since you want to update your contact, you can give following Ampscript a try:
%%[
  Var @result, @sfObject, @id, @fieldName, @fieldValue
  Set @sfObject = "Contact"
  Set @id = _subscriberkey
  Set @fieldName = "eventconfirmation__c"
  Set @fieldValue = "True"

  Set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(@sfObject, @id, @fieldName, @fieldValue)
  If @result == 1 then
]%%

<p>Record with ID %%=v(@id)=%% updated successfully.</p>

%%[ else ]%%

<p>Record with ID %%=v(@id)=%% was not updated.</p>

%%[ EndIf ]%%

Please verify the api name of the field (you need to place it in fieldName variable) as well as the type, as it will decide what you should put in fieldValue variable.

Thanks Lukas, I have a contact list of 100K users and I am trying to capture their date preference for an event. I have 4 available dates which will become 4 CTA buttons. I was using the below ampscript to get the values updated to the DE however, now they want to be able to see it on the CRM against each contact ID, I have had little to no luck : %%[
UpsertData('test-journey-apr',1,'Contact ID',_subscriberkey,'Email',emailaddr,'20 Apr',"true")
]%%

@NDSF it depends on where you want to store it in CRM. Are you using a custom object there to store the event signups? Or do you imagine having it on the Contact record? The latter will limit you to only have one response per contact.

I am trying to store in the Contact Object under a field created  for "Event Confirmation"

@NDSF please see my updated answer and remember to accept it if it was helpful.

Thanks a lot! It worked
